# PC does not work when Graphics card is installed

Tags: graphics-card

I just built a new PC but for some reason when I insert my graphics card and try to boot my pc does not work.

All the fans run and lights, but keyboard, mouse have no lights and monitor goes into standby mode) I know the graphics card works because I tried it on my old pc.

The MB is a Gigabyte B75M-D3H and the graphics card is a Gigabyte AMD Radeon HD7750 1GB DDR5
And before you ask no it does not have a PCI-E power port and I have a 730watt power supply so I think I have enough power.

Help anyone?

PS: the PC works fine with the intergrated graphics card

I've tried these:

- Updating BIOS
- Uninstalling the integrated graphics card and rebooting with th
  graphics card inserted
- changing settings in the BIOS concerning the PCI-E slots
- Inserting my graphics card into the other PCI-E slot on the MB
- Inserting the graphics card into another PC
- Disabling the integrated graphics in the BIOS and inserting the card

Comment: What happens if you disconnect everything else from the MB? What cable are you using? The same for internal and external cards? HDMI? Does the internal card work when you plug the external in?

Comment: What do you mean by "everything else"

Comment: and i am using a RGB and a DVI connector and no the internal card does not work when i insertthr graphics card

Comment: Everything else as in other expansion cards, hard disks, USB devices, DVD drives etc. Can you see the bios screen then?

Comment: No still nothing

Comment: Also: Just to make sure: Please check that the graphics card is 100% properly plugged in and straight in the socket, all the way down. I had the experience that due to the little space on the MB I did not realize that the card needed a significant push to slide properly into the slot in order to work properly.

Comment: I have done that and it still does not work :(

Comment: I would like to point out that the "Possible duplicate" close vote refers to a question that has already been closed as a duplicate using this question as the reference.

Comment: @Murdock: can you specify what bios version you updated to? I have the same motherboard (Gigabyte B75M-D3H, v1.1)  with bios version F13 and it does not work when I insert the Nvidia graphics card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you plug correctly monitor cable to installed graphic card instead of integrated graphic port?
does system make any POST beep?
do you have any other pci-e graphic card to test mother board PCI-E slot?

Comment: i tried inserting both cords in to the motherboard and graphics card but still the pc does not work ,it is not that the pc does not display anything but that no outputs work(and yes it does have a POST beep but when the card is inserted it does not sound,

Comment: wow if after inserting card there is no post, that mean main board failed to initialized post process and stop on code:26., did you update your BIOS to latest version that I think is F13G? and is your motherboard PCB on version 1 or 1.1?

Comment: i am trying to update my BIOS(it is currently F7) but i am having very little success(first time ever attempted) and my PCB is on 1.1

Comment: check your mobo dvd , maybe it has a tools to online update bios.

Comment: thanx man updated my BIOS and it works now

Answer (score 0):

My first guess, based on all your info and previous answers, would be to check your BIOS for settings about graphics (integrated) and PCI-E ports.

As Kaveh suggested, try this card in another computer, and another card in this one, just to be sure.

Comment: Ok so I have been checking my BIOS but it is a 3d bios so i am struggling to find my way around it,and I have asked a friend to come around with his card.As I already said I tested it my old pc that has a PCI-E slot even though the card uses a PCI-E 3 slot it still works.